# Submenu now stretches 100% but has too much padding? I'm guessing

Tags: html, css, nav

I had help getting my sub menu to stretch 100% but now it seems like there's too much padding. That or something to do with left:0; in "li:hover > .subnav-orange".

I'm new here so I'm unable to post images but I'll provide an link to imigur in a comment to give you an idea of what I'm trying to achieve. The links need to stay uniform, which they now are, but the sub menu needs to stay nice and compact under the nav.

http://jsfiddle.net/9m6Kn/4/

```
<div id="wrapper">

  <ul id="nav-wrap">

    <li id="link-one">

    <div class="orange"><a href="#" class="parent-one-link"><span>Digital</span><span>Printing</span></a></div>

    <div class="subnav-orange">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Option1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Option2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Option3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.subnav -->
    </li>


  </ul>

  </div> <!-- wrapper -->

body {
    background-color:#FFF;
    font-size: 62.5%; /* 67.5% or 65.7% */
}

#wrapper {
    width:100%;
    height:85%;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}

#nav-wrap {
    width:100%;
    height:110px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    background-color:#CCC;
}

ul li {
  display:inline-block;
  margin:0;
  float:left;  
  font-size:2.7em;
  font-family: 'allgemeineregular', Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  width:14%;


  height:100%;
  text-align:center;
  color: #FFF;
  line-height:1.1em;
}

.orange {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:#f37028;
}

.orange p {
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.orange a span /* added when link has more than one word */ {
    display:block;
}

.orange a:link, .orange a:visited { 
    padding:0;
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-transform:uppercase;
   -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
   -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
   -ms-transition: all 0.3s;
   -o-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

.orange a:hover { 
    text-decoration:none;  
    color:#231f20;
   -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
   -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
   -ms-transition: all 0.3s;
   -o-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

li .subnav-orange {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;  
  clear: both;
  margin-left: 0;
  background-color:#f37028;
  font-size:0.25em;
  text-align:left !important; 
}

.subnav-orange ul li a:link, a:active, a:visited {
  text-decoration:none;
}

.subnav-orange ul li a:hover { 
  color:#000;
  text-decoration:none;
}

li:hover > .subnav-orange {display:inline-block; left:0;}

.subnav-orange ul {
  margin-left: 0;
  float:left;
  padding:10px 0;
  width:100%;
}

.subnav-orange ul li {  
    margin: 0 10% 0 0 !important;
}
.subnav-orange{width:100%;}
```

Comment: Here's a screenshot of what I'm looking to achieve. imgur.com/hZe0Fb9

Comment: Your absolutely positioned submenu uses the viewport as reference point, since it has no parent element with a `position` differing from the default value `static`. Give `position:relative` to the outer `UL` or the wrapper … and go read up on some basics of layouting with CSS.

Comment: Oh, and stop cooking up “tag soup” … putting `DIV`s around everything is not necessary, just style the semantically appropriate elements _directly_.

Comment: You mean http://jsfiddle.net/9m6Kn/5/ ? You now have several styles for just 1 colour, go for 1 `.subnav` with all the menu styles, then add a background colour list and mix the CSS (ex.); `class="subnav orange"`, `class="subnav blue"`, I'd really clean up this mess before continueing.

Comment: Well, setting up a horizontal sub menu isn't _basic_ and if that were the case there would be more examples online.

Comment: @Compton it actually isn't that different from any other submenu, but you'll see the more you experiment. I just made this so you can see what I mean with cleaner code: http://jsfiddle.net/L5WFX/ It's just a example so left the subs out, but I guess it can be even less messy. Just don't have subnav-orange as style, and then do all those lines of code for every colour... it'll be a pain. Good luck!

Comment: @Marcel - Thanks a tonne for setting up that new fiddle for me. You're right, it can always be less messy. I'm looking forward to setting this up correctly now. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CBroe is exactly right. The absolute positioning causing the width of the dropdown to extend beyond it's parent, unless the parent is position relative. Here's a new fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/9m6Kn/7/

The only thing I did was add the following:

`#nav-wrap {
    position: relative;
}`

Also, I found this site extremely helpful when I was starting to learn css layout. I still find myself looking back to it because it has very straight forward explanations:

http://learnlayout.com/

The other comments about cleaning up your HTML are good recommendations as well. You have a lot of extra elements there when you could be styling elements directly.

Comment: Thanks for the help, to CBroe as well. I'm incorporating code from 2 sources so that can attest for most of the bloated-ness. I built the nav one way and the sub was built in another so tried to clean it up as much as I could before posting. This was just thrown together this morning. Thanks for the link and now that it's working I'll clean up the code and implement it in the way you suggested in your comment.

Comment: I totally understand. Always tough when you're trying to learn something new while combining information from multiple sources. Looks like you've just about got it at this point, so nice work :-)

Comment: Well, I'm not learning something new, unfortunately. I'm a professional web designer. I guess I need to freshen up my skills ;) But I guess that's what happens when you're stuck doing updates for several years. Luckily for me I just got a new job! Thanks for the kind words Steven.